# Request scoped Bean is lost when including pages

Tags: jsf, richfaces

In this main page, I included another, which contains a table with a list of clients.

listinit.jspx:

```
 ....
<rich:tabPanel  id="paneltab"  style="width:800px;">
              <rich:tab  label="Clients">
                    <ui:include src="/listes/listeClients.jspx" />
              </rich:tab>
               ..
 </rich:tabPanel>
 ....
```

listeClients.jspx:

```
 ....
<rich:dataTable id="tblclient"  value="#{ListeBean.clientItems}" var="clnts">
               <f:facet name="header">
                    <rich:columnGroup >
                        <rich:column>                     
                           <h:outputText  value="Name" />
                        </rich:column>
                    </rich:columnGroup>
                </f:facet>
               <rich:column>
                   <h:outputText value="#{clnts.name }" />
               </rich:column>
               <f:facet name="footer">
                   <rich:datascroller />
               </f:facet>
               </rich:dataTable>
       ....
```

in faces-config:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>ListeBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>ListeBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

When I change the scope to ***session***, I could see my table included, but not with ***request*** scope, where the page looks empty but the structure of the table is there. This ***request*** scope worked with similar pages using:

```
<a4j:keepAlive beanName="myPageBean" />
```

But wherever I put this Tag in these two pages, it still the same result.
I hope to find a solution here, thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of JSF is this? 1.2?

Comment: @kolossus  it is JSF 1.x.